# I can't show images in splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
 class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

    void init(){
loadDatas();
super.initState();
}
Future<void> loadDatas()async{
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Image.asset('assets/todo3.png'),
      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```

SplashScreen Widget I created.

```
    void main() {

  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

The part where I call SplashScreen in Main.dart. Am I adding the image in the wrong place? Or should I not make SplashScreen my homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding dependency for splash screen, it will better to create a screen for splash and navigate from that screen.

**Steps for Creating a Splash Screen**

- Make a new screen.
- On the init method of the splash screen, call a async function and add the necessary code to execute in the splash screen.

```
@override
void initState(){
 loadDatas();
 super.initState();
}
Future<void> loadDatas()async{
await Future.Delayed(Duration(seconds:2));
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Flutter so I guess I'm doing something wrong. I added the code you wrote after void main in main.dart. Then I created a new page and made my homepage like home: MyWidget(). I added my image with Image.asset into the loadDatas()async{ } part of the code you wrote. Isn't it supposed to be like this?

Comment: In your homepage, add the splashScreen into home like: "home : SplashScreen()".

Comment: You should have a SplashScreen statefulwidget and use initState method in the statefulwidget to execute the code while the splash screen is being displayed.

Comment: Inside the initState method, you can call the function for executing the necessary code. For example, if you don't have any functions to execute, you can just give a time to wait for the splash screen like the one which I have answered using the Future Function.

Comment: Try following all the steps that I have mentioned. Upvote and accept the answer if it is helpful for you.

Comment: I edited the question, can you take a look please.

Comment: Don't add the Image widget inside the function. Just give the Future delay inside the async function. Add image in the widget tree in build method.

Comment: I was only able to define the super.initState() method in the class. That's why I put the code in the class and added the image to the build. But it just waits for 2 seconds on a white screen and then it shows SplashScreen. My image appears on the page. I edited the code.

Comment: Add image on the splash screen and give an initstate method for splash screen to wait for some seconds in the splash screen to display image.